# Can't start Sagemaker Notebook Instance with a CodeCommit repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker, aws-codecommit

I linked a repo in CodeCommit to Sagemaker. However when I try to start an instance with that repo it fails and I get a message:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/MyRepo/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I think maybe it has something to do with the IAM role. Is there some policy I should add to the AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole. I am completely new to this so please excuse any incorrect usage of terms here.

Answer (score 2):

This is presumably caused by your IAM role ; if you used the UI to create a role, I think by default, it creates a role requiring resources to have "sagemaker" in their ARN (Codecommit repos, S3 buckets...). So you have 2 options:

- Try renaming your repo eg "myrepo-sagemaker"
- Or edit (ask your admin if you don't have the ability) your SM IAM role to be allowed to access MyRepo

Comment: It is for my personal account, do you know how to add access to MyRepo?